# which http status code to return in case of server to third party auth failure

Tags: azure, rest, http

I have a scenario where we have an Azure multi tenant app. Customers grant permission to our service to talk to Azure AD and search (users/AD groups) data from their Azure AD tenant using the authorization code flow granted to our multi-tenant app.

Post the Azure AD setup users login to our UI and try to search users/groups from their AAD tenant. Our service calls AAD APIs using the authorization granted to our multi tenant app.

Now if customer's AAD admin removes the access to our AAD multi tenant app by logging to their AAD console, AAD starts throwing http 403(Forbidden) when our service try to call AAD API to search users.

What http status code should be returned to UI for this particular scenario?
We want to inform the user about this so that they can restore the authorization of our multi tenant app.

I don't think returning http 4xx is a good idea. If we see from the UI prospective it's not a client error.

I think it is some kind of server error. Where our service to AAD connection is broken due to lack of authorization.

Please suggest a reasonable http status code from 5xx series or 4xx series for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client
>   seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
>   server SHOULD **send a representation containing an explanation of the
>   error situation,** and whether it is a temporary or permanent
>   condition.

The payload is the primary way to communicate to the end user what the actual problem is.

HTTP status codes are *meta-data*; the target audience is the general purpose components participating in the message exchange.  On the web, the payload is for the human being; the status codes are for the browser, caches, spiders, and so on.

In your case, the *request* is fine.  In particular, there is nothing that the client can do to improve the result.  So 4xx should be off the table.

> The 5xx (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server
>   is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the
>   requested method.

The 5xx class of status codes is a lot less specific than the 4xx class (primarily because there are no corrective actions that can be taken by the other components).

The real options available to you are

- 500 Internal Server Error
- 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable is interesting in that it has a bunch of Retry-After semantics defined; you get communicate to the general purpose components an estimate of when the problem may be fixed, and then those components can judge what to do with that information.

> The 503 (Service Unavailable) status code indicates that the server
>   is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload
>   or scheduled maintenance, which will likely be alleviated after some
>   delay.

So if you think you can estimate the delay before things are working again, then 503 may make sense.

> The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server
>   encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling
>   the request.

That's a perfectly satisfactory alternative.  "We are unexpectedly broken right now".

Again the payload of the 5xx response can be used to communicate more specific semantics to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep with 4xx.

> HTTP 403 is a standard HTTP status code communicated to clients by an
>   HTTP server to indicate that access to the requested (valid) URL by
>   the client is Forbidden for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the end your application reaches a status where the current user is not allowed to do something. Depending on how technically skilled your average user is you can give her a more or less technical information. Since you seem to be able to define what particular is wrong you have the chance to tell the user about it and how she should react. In my opinion no HTTP code is needed then. There is not really a benefit of giving it to the user (except she is technically skilled). So I would go with a good explanation in the UI (and maybe a text in small font size holding the HTTP code). But this is only my opinion how I would do it.

In the end this also depends on the business process you are implementing with your software. And so **I would recommend you to ask your question to the person(s) responsible for the business part behind the software** (like a Product Owner). Also asking your UX designer(s) would be a good idea, if you have some.