# REST API status when external APIs are down - Best Practices

Tags: rest, web-services, http

I'm looking for guidance on good practices when it comes to returning errors from a REST API. I'm working on a new API so I can take it any direction.

In my case client invokes my API which internally invokes some external APIs. In case of success no problem, but in case of error responses from the far end(external cloud APIs) I am not sure what is industry standard for such services. Am currently thinking of returning 200 OK and then a json payload which details about the external API errors.

So what is the industry recommendations? Good practices (please explain why!) and also, from a client pov, what kind of error handling in the REST API makes life easier for the client code?

Comment: You may want to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861584/which-http-status-code-to-return-in-case-of-server-to-third-party-auth-failure/58863781#58863781 to see if it matches your question

Comment: It seems answering this question is rather opinion based, but following the http standard (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is the key

Answer (score 7):

The failure you're asking about is one that has occurred within the internals of the service itself, though it is having external dependencies, so a **5XX** status code range is the correct choice. 503 Service Unavailable looks perfect for the situation you've described.

5XX codes used for telling the client that even though the request was fine, the server has had some kind of problem fulfilling the request. On the other hand,

4XX codes are used to tell the client that it has done something wrong in request (and that the server is just fine, thanks). 
[Sections 10.4 and 10.5 of the HTTP 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10) explain the different purposes of 4XX and 5XX codes.

Answer (score 1):

Our colleagues have already provided the links / explanations about the HTTP status codes so you should learn them and find the most appropriate in your case.

I'll more concentrate on what can influence your decisions, assuming you've learnt the status codes.

Basically, You should understand what are the business implications of the flow triggered by client when he/she calls "your" API. The client doesn't know anything about the external cloud API you're working with and doesn't really care whether it works or not, the client works with your application.

If so, when the remote system returns some kind of error (and yes, different error statuses should give you a clue of what's wrong with the remote system), its your business decision about how to handle this error, and depending on this decision you might want to "behave" differently in the interaction with a client.

Here are some examples:

1. You know that the remote system breaks extremely rarely. But once its unavailable, you system doesn't work as well.
   In this case you can might consider to retry the call to remote system if it failed. And if you still out of luck - then return some error status. Probably something like 5XX
2. You know that the data provided by remote client is not really important, on the other hand when the client calls your API its better to provide "something" even if its not really up-to-date than nothing. Think about the remote system that provides the "recommended movies" by some client id. And you're building a portal (netflix style). If this recommended movies service is down for some reason, it doesn't make sense to fail the whole portal page (think about the awful user experience). In this case you might want to "pre-cache" some generic list of movies, and use it as a fallback in case of failure of that remote service. In this case obviously you should return 2XX status in any case.
3. More advanced architecture. You know that the remote service fails often, and you can continue to work when its down. In this case maybe you will want to choose an "asynchronous" style of interaction with the client. For example: the client calls your rest and you respond immediately with an "Accepted" status code (202). You can save this id with status in some Database so that when the user "asks for status of the ticket by ticket id" you'll be able to query the DB. The point is that you return immediately. Then you might want to send the message with the task to some messaging system and once the consumer will pick the message, it will be processed and the db will be updated. As long as the remote service fails the message will get back to queue still being "unprocessed" (usually messaging systems can implement this behavior).  Now at some point in time, the remote system starts responding, and all the messages get processed. Now their status in DB is "done". 
   So its up to client to ask "what happens" /or you can implement some push model with web sockets or something (its not REST style communication anymore in this case). But the point is that at some point in time the client will receive "OK, we're done with the ticket ID" (status 200). In this case the client can call a special endpoint and consume the stored results that you'll store in the DB as well (again status 200)

Bottom line, as you see, HTTP return codes are just an indicator, but its up to you how to organize the process of interconnection with the client and the relevant HTTP statuses will be derived from your decisions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 503 - Service Unavailable - as the error. Reason -

- This is considering the case that the API operation cannot be completed without response from the external API. This is similar to my DB not responding. So my API is unavailable for service till the external service is back online.
- As an API client, I am not concerned whether the API server internally invokes other APIs or not. I am just concerned with the result of the API server. So it does not matter to the client whether I am a proxy or not - hence, I would avoid 502 (Bad Gateway) and 504 (Gateway Timeout). These error can put the client into wrong assumption that the Gateway between the client and our service is causing trouble.
- As suggested by @developerjack, I would also recommend to - "Include a `Retry-After` header so that your HTTP client knows not to spam you with retries until after X time. This means less error traffic for you, and better request planning for the client."

Answer (score 0):

HTTP calls are between client and server, and so the error codes should reflect where the error or fault lies on either side of that relationship. Just because its downstream to you doesn't mean the HTTP client needs to care about that.

Given this, you should be returning a 5xx error because the fault is not with the client, its with the server (or its downstream services).  Returning a 2xx (see below for caveat) would be incorrect because the HTTP call did not succeed, and a 4xx would be incorrect because it's not the client's fault.

Digging into specific 5xx's you can return:

- A 504 or 502 might be appropriate if you specifically want to signal that your service is acting as a gateway/proxy.
- A 523 is [unofficial but used by cloudflare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) to specifically signal that an upstream/origin service is unreachable
- A 500 (with a human and machine readable error body) is a safe default that simply indicates "there is something not right with the server and its services right now".

Now, in terms of best practice, there are some techniques you can use to either reduce the 500 errors, or make it easier on the clients to respond/react to this 5xx response.

- Put in place retries within your service. If your service is working and the fault is downstream, and can successfully store the client's request to retry later when downstream services are available then you can still respond with a 2xx and the client knows that their request will be submitted. A great example of this might be a user sign up workflow; you can process the signup at your side, and then queue the welcome email to retry later if your email provider is unavailable.
- Have *both* human descriptions, machine error codes and links in your API responses. Human descriptions are useful when debugging and developing against your service. Machine codes mean clients can index/track and code up specific code paths to a given scenario, and links to your docs mean you can alway provide more information. Even better is including any specific ID's for you to trace instances of this error in case the HTTP client needs to reach out for support (though this will be heavily dependant on your logging & telemetry). Here's an example:

  ```
  {
      "error_code": 1234,
      "description": "X happened with Y because of Z.",
      "learn_more": "https://dev.my.app/errors/1234",
      "id": "90daa63b-f5ac-4c33-97d5-0801ade75a5d"
  }
  ```
- Include a [`Retry-After`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) header so that your HTTP client knows not to spam you with retries until after X time. This means less error traffic for you, and better request planning for the client.